# Can Djinni generate necessary code from C++ global functions?

Tags: android, c++, ios, djinni

I'm researching using [libbitcoin](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin) for a project I'm going to work on, and interested in using Djinni to create the glue code for ObjC/Java for iOS and Android, respectively.

It appears there are many global functions in libbitcoin, inside a namespace, but not inside a class. I have only seen Djinni to generate a few types (classes, enums, flags, records) but I have not been able to find if a global function can be accommodated.

Is this doable? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not feasible since djinni produces Java bindings and there are no global functions in Java.

What you might do is to create a class with a set of static methods that will forward calls to global functions:

```
Bitcoin = interface +c {
  static callGlobalFun1();
  static callGlobalFun2(param: string);
  static callGlobalFun3(): string;
}
```

Comment: Great idea. I will give this a try and report back. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Please let me know if that solved your problem.